# Show on hover, hide with button contained in popup div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-hover

In the code below, I know I have to be doing something wrong, in the jsfiddle it works perfectly, but when I look at in my chrome or any other browser, the code breaks right after it shows the ".popup" div. What am I doing wrong? I found similar code on this site, but none with the button to hide it in the popup itself.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.featured')
    .mouseenter(function() {
      $('.popup').show();
    })
  $('.exit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.popup').hide();
  });


});
```

```css
.popup {
  display: none;
}
.featured {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="featured">FEATURED</a>



<div class="popup">
<ul>
<li>EYE</li>
<li>LOVE</li>
<li>ROCK</li>
<li>AND</li>
<li>ROLL</li>
<li><input class="exit" value="close" type=button /></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: so what's not working?

Comment: close the anchor correctly

Comment: Sorry, threw it up here in a hurry, closed the anchor, and it works here still for some reason, on the JSFIDDLE only.When I launch it from expression web the code breaks after it .show() executes, the button is rendered useless. I mean I literally copy and pasted it into my editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<a>` tag isn't closed `</a>`

I don't have any problems running it here in this jsfiddle:

```
<a class="featured">FEATURED</a>



<div class="popup">
<ul>
<li>EYE</li>
<li>LOVE</li>
<li>ROCK</li>
<li>AND</li>
<li>ROLL</li>
<li><input class="exit" value="close" type=button /></li>
</ul>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.featured')
    .mouseenter(function() {
      $('.popup').show();
    })

  $('.exit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.popup').hide();
  });


});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eg2zp0fp/

Comment: Is there another way to achieve this same effect?

Comment: Yes, you can use jquery/javascript to change the class or even the individual attribute of the item.

Example:
$('.exit').css("display", "none");

$('.exit').toggleClass( "show" )

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm, I think it had something to do with the fact that on my draft site, that class (.'featured') was assigned to an image, not the <a> tag. Don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: No problem ^_^
Glad I could help!